# Rails Metaprograming/Refactoring/DRYing the controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, metaprogramming

I have a controller with several actions. Many follow this pattern:

```
def favorites
  @favorites = Favorite.where(organization_id: @resource.id).page(params[:page]).per(50)
end
```

It's not just favorites, but there's also downloads, searches, lists etc and they're all so similar that I wanted to create a method that I could call in a before_filter.  Something like this:

```
def set_instance_variable
  subject = __method__
  class = __method__.singularize.constantize
  instance_variable = self.class.instance_variable_set("@#{subject}", "#{class}.where(organization_id: @resource.id).page(params[:page]).per(50)")
end
```

The syntax might be a little off here, but I know this won't work because `__method__` will always be set_instance_variable and not the parent method where it is called.

Is there a way to dynamically set instance variables based on the method that defines them? Is this example above even on the right track?

Comment: Looks like `has_many` association to me (especially that you mentioned `OrganizationsController` below). If you defined it you would be able to set `@resource` (`@organization`) in `before_filter` and then call `@resource.favorites`, `@resource.downloads` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the way the CanCan library handles this problem. With CanCan, you call a class method at the top of your controller:

```
load_resource
```

CanCan then looks at:

- the action you're in to determine whether you want a collection or singular resource,
- the name of the controller to determine the class to load
- authorization rules to add scopes like your organization_id restriction (cancan is also a library for defining these)

I think pagination and resource loading are separate things, and you shouldn't put them in the same method. I'd shoot for an interface like this:

```
class FavoritesController
  load_resource
  paginate_resource only: [:index]

  def show
    # @favorite loaded here
  end

  def index
    # @favorites loaded and paginated here
  end
end
```

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb#L29

If it makes more sense in your application to have non-restful resources, then you can't re-use the convention-based thing cancan is and instead have to define your own function. Consider something like this:

```
def favorites
  @favorites = load_resource Favorite
end


private

def load_resource(klass)
  klass.where(organization_id: @resource.id).page(params[:page]).per(50)
end
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll look into this. One immediate concern is that all of these actions are in the OrganizationsController, not the FavoritesController. This isn't a typically scaffolded controller and perhaps that's adding to the problem. Maybe it doesn't matter with cancan?

Comment: Well, it's easiest to DRY things up and to re-use things if you're following standard conventions. A favorites resource would typically be the index action of a favorites controller, not a separate non-restful resource in another controller.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good compromise. I'll have to set the instance variable for each action but at least it will look better as a smaller line. Maybe it's over complicating things to guess the Class name based on the action and make it into a before filter. I can live with this solution.